# VBA to download automatically generated files from a webpage requiring login

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, authentication, automation, download

I am trying to download and save to a specific location for further processing an automatically generated file from a portal which requires login. This makes it impossible for me to copy any of the actual data, but here is what I did so far:

Successfully

1. Created Internet Explorer instance
2. Navigated to desired url and logged in
3. Navigated to desired url after login

But then I got stuck. The file I'm trying to download does not have a static url, I don't even know how to get it. A javascript starts the download in IE, but I have been unable to find hWnd's of the buttons in the download dialog (Using windows 7, the class is probably something other than "Button").

The javascript that initiates the download is actually generating an url and navigating to that url and is something like:

```
url="domain" + var + "string" + var=;
goto url
```

I can generate this url in my program as well, but when I download the contents of this url, I get an html document and not the file that I want.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you provide more information, eg. some sample urls, the javascript code, the html response ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't, since the website is of our customer's. I don't want to risk exposing anything from a website that only our sales personnel has the authorization to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating the url and trying to download the contents of the document was not the right path. Instead, I navigated to the URL, which resulted in download initiation.

I finally managed to automate the download window using FindWindow and FindWindowEx. Using Spy++ I was able to see that the buttons were not directly children of the download window, but there were some more "windows" with different classes in between.

I think I will try to get more "intelligence" before I assume in the future.